# Changing a pointer to an array in C

Tags: c++, c

I have got a structure and in it a pointer to a 2D array. But when I try to assign an actual 2D array to that pointer I do not succeed - compiler says that my pointer is a pointer to a 1D array.

Here's my code:

```
typedef GLfloat Vertex2f[2];
typedef GLfloat TextureCoordinate[2];

typedef struct { 
    GLuint texture_name;  // OpenGL ID of texture used for this sprite 
    Vertex2f *vertices; // array of vertices 
    TextureCoordinate *texture_coords; // texture vertices to match

    GLubyte *vertex_indices;
} game_sprite;

void loadState()
{
    game_sprite ballSprite;

    createAndLoadTexture("ball.png", &ballSprite.texture_name);

    const Vertex2f tempVerticesArray[4] =  {
        {-100.0f, -100.0f},
        {-100.0f, 100.0f},
        {100.0f, 100.0f},
        {100.0f, -100.0f}
    };

    ballSprite.vertices = &tempVerticesArray; //The problem appears to be here
}
```

How can I make it work?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have two problems.  First is that `tempVerticesArray` is `const`.  You can't assign a pointer to a `const` value (`&tempVerticesArray`) to a pointer to a non-`const` variable (`ballSprite.vertices`) without a typecast, so the compiler is complaining.  You should modify the `vertices` data member to be of the type `const Vertex2f *`, assuming you're not actually modifying that data ever.

The second problem is that as soon as `loadState()` ends, the variable `tempVerticesArray` goes out of scope, and so any dangling pointers to it (specifically `ballSprite.vertices`) are invalid.  You should make `tempVerticesArray` a `static` variable so it's not a stack variable that can go out of scope.  This is assuming that the `ballSprite` object is used after that function ends, which I'm guessing it does based on context.

If you *do* need to modify your vertices after initialization, you'll need to allocate for each `ballSprite` its own set of vertex data (e.g. using `malloc()`) and copy the vertex data in (e.g. using `memcpy()`).  If you don't, all `ballSprite` instances will share a pointer to the same vertex data, and when you modify it, they will all be affected.

Answer (score 3):

My C is a little rusty, but shouldn't that be:

```
ballSprite.vertices = tempVerticesArray;
```

Comment: In C/C++ tempVerticesArray has type "Vertex2f*" and &tempVerticesArray has type "Vertex2f[2]*". The first is a pointer to the (first) element, the second is a pointer to an array.

Comment: No.  Both `ballSprite.vertices = tempVerticesArray` and `ballSprite.vertices = &tempVerticesArray` are equivalent.  `tempVerticesArray` has type `const Vertex2f[2]`, and it decays into a pointer to a first element (of type `const Vertex2f*`).  `&tempVerticesArray` has type `const Vertex2f (*)[2]`, which is a compatible type with `const Vertex2f*`.  The problem is with `const` correctness.

Comment: No, they are not compatible pointer types. One is a pointer to a Vertex2f, the other is a pointer to an array of Vertex2f's.

Comment: The types of the expressions are *not* compatible; remember that Vertext2F is a typedef for `GLFloat [2]`, so the expression `ballSprite.vertices` is of type `GLFloat (*)[2]` and the type of the expression `&tempVerticesArray` is `GLFloat (*)[4][2]`, which are *not* compatible; the expression `tempVerticesArray` has type `GLFloat [4][2]`, which will be implicitly converted to `GLFloat (*)[2]`.   **EDIT** The `const` issue doesn't help.

Answer (score 3):

in C an array is in fact a pointer to the first member,  so when you do

```
ballSprite.vertices = &tempVerticesArray;
```

you are actually trying to assign to ballSprite.vertices the value of a pointer to a pointer

drop the &  and you'll be fine with `ballSprite.vertices = tempVerticesArray;`

Comment: In C++, an array is not a pointer, but decays to one in certain contexts.

Comment: @gf: That's true in C as well.

Comment: @jamesdlin: ah, wasn't entirely sure.

Answer (score 2):

Just to clarify, I don't think

```
Vertex2f *vertices
```

declares a "2D array", it is a 1-dimensionnal array of Vertex2f.

But as pointed by Mitch, the issue is probably that tempVerticesArray, as declared here, is a 1d-array, which is the same as a pointer to a Vertex2f. So &tempVerticesArray is the address of this pointer (a Vertex2f * * ).

Answer (score 1):

You could use either

```
ballSprite.vertices = tempVerticesArray;
```

or

```
ballSprite.vertices = &tempVerticesArray[0];
```

Answer (score 1):

You might want to allocate memory for the pointer to hold the data. Then memcpy the temporary array to the newly allocated memory. If you're just trying to make the pointer reference the array directly, you might have an issue when you leave that function. The temporary array made on the stack will be freed before you can use the pointer elsewhere.